# Unable to change the dark mode on the SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, themes, ios-darkmode

I tried toggle the dark mode, I know Swift 4 or 5 I use the code:

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

But in SwiftUI, seem nothing way I can do that...how can I toggle the dark mode rest of app? I tried do many method and search everywhere but couldn't find any luck. Even I tried use didSet but no luck, it give me the error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to force dark mode for the whole app you can add the `User Interface Style` to the `Info.plist` and set it to `Dark`

[image]

You can also add the following line to the Scene/App Delegate

`window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark`

Comment: I would like to have both support...I am trying to figure out how to add the toggle so I can set three different dark mode - Automatic, Dark, and Light. On my old app with Swift 4, I have no problem but with SwiftUI, I am trying to figure out how to toggle Dark Mode on my new app

Comment: The plist property `User Interface Style` is no longer available or has been renamed to `Appearance`

Comment: To add a row to pList, right-click, then select "Add Row". Once the row is added, the key column will have a drop-down where the relevant key (e.g. Appearance) can be selected.